# C# Collecting lower quality chains list for a given certificate

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate, x509

I am new to the world of security in C#. I wanted to know how to get the list of simple plus lower quality chains for any certificate.

Windows has provided a function CertGetCertificateChain() which builds a certificate chain context starting from an end certificate and going back till root. Refer [this msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376078(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Refer to "CERT_CHAIN_RETURN_LOWER_QUALITY_CONTEXTS" flag which is provided to collect the lower quality chains.

I am using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespaces provided by .Net framework.
So wanted to know how I can achieve the same in C# as well?

Need help in achieving this.

Thanks in advance!

Tausifahamad H. T.

Comment: .NET doesn't include such functionality, you have to call C functions directly by using p/invoke.

Comment: I thought there will be an option to do this, but let me go ahead with your recommendation. Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me on how to use Pinvoke for CertGetCertificateChain function.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Crypt32, as you mentioned, this is not possible in .NET hence I used PInvoke to call C++ API's exposed by Windows and it worked.